# Trim More than 20 Characters

Tags: regex, powershell

I am working on a script that will generate AD usernames based off of a csv file. Right now I have the following line working.

```
Select-Object @{n=’Username’;e={$_.FirstName.ToLower() + $_.LastName.ToLower() -replace "[^a-zA-Z]" }}
```

As of right now this takes the name and combines it into a AD friendly name. However I need to name to be shorted to no more than 20 characters. I have tried a few different methods to shorten the username but I haven't had any luck.

Any ideas on how I can get the username shorted?

Comment: Is this question just about how to truncate a string at 20 characters?  `$truncated = (if ($str.Length -gt 20) { $str.Substring(0, 20) } else { $str })`.

Comment: `-replace'(?<=.{20}).*'`

Answer (score 3):

Probably the most elegant approach is to use a positive lookbehind in your replacement:

```
... -replace '(?<=^.{20}).*'
```

This expression matches the remainder of the string only if it is preceded by 20 characters at the beginning of the string (`^.{20}`).

Another option would be a replacement with a capturing group on the first 20 characters:

```
... -replace '^(.{20}).*', '$1'
```

This captures at most 20 characters at the beginning of the string and replaces the whole string with just the captured group (`$1`).

Answer (score 2):

To truncate a string in PowerShell, you can use the .NET `String::Substring` method.  The following line will return the first `$targetLength` characters of `$str`, or the whole string if `$str` is shorter than that.

```
if ($str.Length -gt $targetLength) { $str.Substring(0, $targetLength) } else { $str }
```

If you prefer a regex solution, the following works (thanks to @PetSerAl)

```
$str -replace "(?<=.{$targetLength}).*"
```

A quick measurement shows the regex method to be about 70% slower than the substring method (942ms versus 557ms on a 200,000 line logfile)

Comment: Id give you two for pointing out the regex costs. Regex (imo) should always be used with great skepticism and caution...

Answer (score 2):

```
$str[0..19] -join ''
```

e.g.

```
PS C:\> 'ab'[0..19]
ab

PS C:\> 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[0..19] -join ''
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
```

Which I would try in your line as:

```
Select-Object @{n=’Username’;e={(($_.FirstName + $_.LastName) -replace "[^a-z]").ToLower()[0..19] -join '' }}
```

([a-z] because PowerShell regex matches are case in-senstive, and moving .ToLower() so you only need to call it once).

And if you are using Strict-Mode, then why not check the length to avoid going outside the bounds of the array with the delightful:

```
$str[0..[math]::Min($str.Length, 19)] -join ''
```

Comment: `Set-StrictMode -Version 3; 'ab'[0..19]`